# Externally linked Javascript file won't execute, but the function works

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

This is more than likely a very simple question.

I have an external javascript file linked to my main html file. The link is good, but the functions won't run when called. I know for a fact that the function works because I can copy and paste it into my main html file. However, the instant it is in an external file, the function won't run.

What am I doing wrong?

Snippet of my main html file:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="VRC_Index_Ajax_Functions.js"></script><--The issue file-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validations.js"></script> <--This file works-->
```

This is my entire VRC_Index_Ajax_Functions.js file. The function I'm dealing with mainly is showHint(str). I will mention that the showHint_l(str) doesn't work within this file either. I'm not sure about the other functions yet.

```
 //VRC_Index_Ajax_Function.js - ajax calls


//Publisher Hints - First Name
function showHint(str)
{
 if (str.length==0)
 {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
   return;
 }
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}

//Publisher Hints - Last Name
function showHint_l(str)
{
 if (str.length==0)
{
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
 return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint2.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

 //Ajax function for checking out territories - it will simply call the php file
 function checkOut(params)
{
var urlString = params;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
}
//Setup for post submission 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.open("POST","checkOut.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(urlString);
}



//Function that displays checked out territories
function displayChOut(params)
{
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("displayCO").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_checked_out.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
 }

 function checkStatus()
 {
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
    document.getElementsByName("numberOut").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST", "checkStatus_php.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

I really have no idea why it would suddenly not work in an external file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the `//VRC_Index_Ajax_Function.js - ajax calls` part? Are these functions inside the result of an ajax call?

Comment: Oh, I just create a comment containing the name of the file inside all of my files. It's a way for me to see the name when I'm working on it. The functions I'm trying to call are in that file.

Comment: that's a lot of javascript - when it doesn't work, what does it do and what errors show up in the console (open firebug/developer tools and look)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a closing brace on a function:

```
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length === 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

//Publisher Hints - Last Name
function showHint_l(str) {
    if (str.length === 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint2.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

//Ajax function for checking out territories - it will simply call the php file
function checkOut(params) {
    var urlString = params;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        //Setup for post submission 
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "checkOut.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send(urlString);
    }
} // Here



//Function that displays checked out territories
function displayChOut(params) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("displayCO").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax_checked_out.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function checkStatus() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementsByName("numberOut").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "checkStatus_php.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Not quite related to your question but a point of maintainability:

`xmlhttp` is a global due to this code.

It's assigned to without being scoped.

To make a variable local to a function scope do this:

```
function somefunc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I find it odd how a bracket can cause an entire file not function when it's not even the function I'm calling.

Comment: Mlagma, most languages will respond that way.

Comment: javascript works that way, since its not a compiled language.

Comment: @thescientist it doesn't really relate to whether or not it's a compiled language.

Comment: I get what you're saying. I was just irritated that my compiler didn't catch that - I can't fathom why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move all the js include to the end of the html file.
Maybe you call this function before the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look through the code yet, but if one part of the javascript file is malformed then the entire file will not work.  If you are missing a curly brace {} or a parenthesis, or any other syntax error.

Comment: So, if one of the functions is bad, it could affect the one I'm trying to run?

Comment: if the javascript on page1.js is malformed, then all the code on page1.js will not be in context and non of the functions can be used.  If you are calling a function from page1.js from page2.js it won't work because the function won't exist.  Does that make sense?